# How to remove values below 0 in 2D array and squaring remaining value using python lambda map

Tags: python, arraylist, lambda

```
list1 = [[-1,2,3,4,-2], [-4,3,2]]
 
output = list(
    map(
        lambda l: list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, l)),
        list1
        )
    )
 
print(output)
```

The code prints as

```
[[2, 3, 4], [3, 2]]
```

but I need ans as

```
[[4, 9, 16], [9, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a list comprehension in your lamda function and it works as expected.

```
list1 = [[-1, 2, 3, 4, -2], [-4, 3, 2]]

output = list(
    map(
        lambda l: [i**2 for i in list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, l))] ,
        list1
    )
)

print(output)
```

Output:
`[[4, 9, 16], [9, 4]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
>>> list1 = [[-1,2,3,4,-2], [-4,3,2]]
>>> output = [[e**2 for e in l if e>0] for l in list1]
>>> output
[[4, 9, 16], [9, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the lambda and the map:

```py
list1 = [[-1,2,3,4,-2], [-4,3,2]]
 
output = list(
    map(
        lambda l: [i**2 for i in l if i > 0], 
        list1
        )
    )   
 
print(output)
```